# Use typings for ES6 class inside class itself

Tags: typescript, webstorm, typescript-typings

I have an existing ES6 class `ClassA.js` like this:

```
module.exports = class A {
  test(param) {
    console.log(param)
  }

  test2(param) {
    this.test() // no warning here
  }
}
```

Also I have a typings file `ClassA.d.ts`

```
export type A = {
  test(param: string): void
  test2(param: string): void
}
```

Also I have an `index.js`

```
const A = require('./ClassA');

const a = new A();
a.test(1);
```

This as expected gives an compiler error using WebStorm as `test` expects a `string`.

However I don't get a warning for `this.test()` inside `ClassA.js` which is lacking the param. Also if calling `this.(1)` doesn't throw a warning.

Is there a way to have warnings also inside the class itself? Also can I use `tsc` to include `ClassA.js` and get a compiler warning for wrong class in `index.js` and also inside `ClassA.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typings are not supposed to be used for linting the libraries themselves, you can't make the IDE (or tsc compiler) to use them for this purpose.
I'd suggest using JSDoc annotations instead, like:

```
module.exports = class A {
    /**
     * @param {string} param
     */
    test(param) {
        console.log(param)
    }
    /**
     * @param {string} param
     */
    test2(param) {
        this.test() // no warning here
    }
}
```